# Why is the canonical module of a local Gorenstein ring $R$ of dimension 0 isomorphic to the injective hull of the residue field?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R,m,k)$ be a local Gorenstein ring of dimension 0, that is $R$ has finite injective dimension (see for instance the definition in *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* from Bruns and Herzog).

> In Definition 3.3.1 in *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* from Bruns and Herzog a **canonical module** of $R$ is defined as a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module of type 1 and of finite injective dimension.

Moreover, in Theorem 3.3.7 in the same book we have

> If $(R,m,k)$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then $R$ is Gorenstein if and only if a canonical module $\omega_R$ exists and is isomorphic to $R$, i.e. $\omega_R \cong R$.

Now in Eisenbuds book *Commutative Algebra with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry* the author defines

> a zero-dimensional local ring $(R,m,k)$ is Gorenstein if and only if the injective hull $E(k)$ of $k$ is isomorphic to $R$.

Now since I assume that these definitions should be consistent, there should be some reference that proves that for local Gorenstein rings $(R,m,k)$ of dimension 0 (using the definition of Bruns and Herzog) the injective hull $E(k)$ is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: Just a note. The canonical module of any dimension $0$ local ring is isomorphic to $E(k)$. The Gorenstein hypothesis is not needed.

Comment: @metalspringpro Could you provide a reference for this please?

Comment: Sure, by definition of canonical module, you need only to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(k,E(k)) \cong k$. Then $E(k)$ fits the criteria to be a canonical module, since it is already injective. The needed fact follows if you already know $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,E(k))$ is a duality on finitely generated modules. Or one could appeal to something like Theorem 3.2.8 in "Cohen-Macaulay Rings" by Bruns and Herzog. The whole of their chapter 3 is a nice reference for this subject.

Comment: @metalspringpro I don't see how 3.2.8 helps, but if I am correct, 3.2.12 (a) states $Ext_R^0(k,E(k)) \simeq k$ and thats what is needed, isn't it?

Comment: Either 3.2.7 or 3.2.8 tell us (taking $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$, the unique prime ideal of $R$) that if $I$ is an injective module, then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(k,I)$ is the number of copies of $E(k)$ in a direct sum decomposition of $I$. In particular, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(k,E(k)) \cong k$. Yes 3.2.12 also contains this statement, but if you notice, the proof of part a) is just a reference to 3.2.7. Note that $\operatorname{Ext}^0_R(-,-)=\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,-)$.

Comment: @metalspringpro Thank you, that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over an arbitrary CM ring you have $\Omega$ a canonical module if
$$\text{Ext}_{R}^{n}(k,\Omega)\simeq
\begin{cases}
k &\mbox{ if } n=\text{dim}\,R;\\
0 &\mbox{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Now, if $\text{dim}\,R=0$ and $\Omega$ is canonical then $\Omega$ is injective by the definition and the fact there are no other prime ideals. Yet then $\Omega\simeq E(k)^{(n)}$ for $n=\text{dim Hom}_{R}(k,\Omega)$, but this is just equal to 1 by definition so $\Omega\simeq E(k)$.

But if $R$ Gorenstein then $R\simeq \Omega$ which is then isomorphic to $E(k)$ if $\text{dim}\,R=0$.

**Edit:**

Over any commutative noetherian ring $R$ and for any $R$-module $M$, it is known that
$$E(M)\simeq\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}R}E(R/\mathfrak{p})^{(\mu_{\mathfrak{p}})}$$
where $\mu_{\mathfrak{p}}=\text{dim}_{R_{\mathfrak{p}}}\text{Hom}_{R}(R/\mathfrak{p},M)_{\mathfrak{p}}$. In our case (when $R$ is local of dimension zero), we know $\Omega$ is injective so is its own injective hull, and $\mu_{\mathfrak{m}}= \text{dim Hom}_{R}(k,\Omega)=1 $ as $R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you deduce $\Omega\simeq E(k)^{(n)}$ for $n=\text{dim Hom}_{R}(k,\Omega)$?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me!

Comment: @windsheaf I've edited to answer your question